# Dexie JS: very large IndexedDB but empty tables

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, dexie

I have an application that uses vanilla javascript to show an openlayers map, people tap on a location and can add pictures. I'm using Dexie JS to store the data between pages until the user is ready to send everything. After everyting is uploaded, the record is deleted.

But Edge and Chrome keep chrashing on desktop and on mobile device. And it seems to have something to do with IndexedDB being to big.

There is a "main" record that holds details and a "related" table that holds the images.

To add a record, this is my code:

```
export const AddRecord = async (tablename, data) => {
let table = db.table(tablename);
let added = await table.add(data);
return added;
}
```

To delete a record, this is my code:

```
export const DeleteRecord = async (tablename, id) => {
let table = db.table(tablename);
let deleted = await table.delete(id);
return deleted;
}
```

But this isn't really the problem. Everything is executed and after uploading, records are deleted. But indexeddb keeps taking up space

I cleared all data and started with this

[image: screenshot before]

I added 1 record containing an id and three fields

[image: screenshot one record]

Storage is already up by 3MB which seems a lot for just one record. But that doesn't really matter because everything gets deleted anyway

[image: screenshot storage with one record]

But after uploading 25 images (with a size between 1.5MB and 2.5MB, i get this result

[image: screenshot after]

The tables i used to store the data is empty. What is taking up the space? Do i need to "purge" to completly delete all left over data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe seems similar to what happens when large ArrayBuffers are being indexed - see https://dexie.org/docs/Version/Version.stores()#warning

By your description I don't see how you are indexing the tables, but if this is the case, the solution is to not index large ArrayBuffers or Uint8Arrays etc. Index only the fields that you are going to use in your `where` queries - other properties can be added without being indexed.

For example, let's say you have declared your Dexie like so:

```js
const db = new Dexie('myDB');
db.version(1).stores({
  imageEntries: '++id,image'
});
```

Then if you let add the image as so:

```js
const img = new UInt8Array(size);
db.imageEntries.add({image: img});
```

...then this will make the database have to create lots of data for the "image" index along with the image data.

The correct way of indexing the related table is more like:

```js
const db = new Dexie('myDB');
db.version(2).stores({
  imageEntries: '++id' // Only the primary key here.
});
```

Remember, dexie does not enforce you to list all properties in `version().stores()`, but just the ones that you need to query on.

Comment: you nailed it. I don't remember reading that warning but i should have. My mistake. I based my code on some samples i found online so i never really read the dexie docs

Comment: I'm glad to hear this was the issue! This is a common misunderstanding and anyone could easily do this mistake. Please upvote my answer if you have enough credits to do so - it could help other people facing the same strange behaviour.