# Write buffer is failing for large size dexie

Tags: indexeddb, dexie

I am trying to store parquet file data as buffer in indexeddb, but is failing with no error logged
the file size is around 430mb

```
  const db = new Dexie('database');

  db.version(1).stores({ datasets: 'token,data' });

  const writeStart = performance.now();

  db.table('datasets').put({
    token: `taxi123`,
    data: file.data,
  });
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6luta.png)

But I can overcome it by removing the field data in schema like below and it works:

```
  const db = new Dexie('database');

  db.version(1).stores({ datasets: 'token' });

  const writeStart = performance.now();

  db.table('datasets').put({
    token: `taxi123`,
    data: file.data,
  });
```

[after success full upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6kLb.png)

Wanted to see any error log but which was not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to [Dexie JS: very large IndexedDB but empty tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76686618/dexie-js-very-large-indexeddb-but-empty-tables/76686760#76686760)

Basically, large buffers should never be indexed. First because you have no reason to index it. Second because it will make life very hard for indexeddb to maintain the index. You want to store it, yes! But do you want to search for it as a key in a where-clause? Probably no. If you really want to index a large buffer, please store a hash of it in another property and index the hash instead. Remember that you don't need to list all properties in dexie schema, just the ones to index